# Max IEndpointInstances per process

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

Is there an upper limit to the number of unique `IEndpointInstances` that be hosted within in a single process?

I'm considering a design that will see up to a 100 unique `IEndpointInstances`, all listening on separate queues, be active simultaneously.

**Will this cause a problem for NServiceBus?**  Could the process deadlock or spin up so many threads as to be unresponsive and useless?

The question [NServiceBus - How to get separate queue for each message type receiver subscribes to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411638/nservicebus-how-to-get-separate-queue-for-each-message-type-receiver-subscribe) seems to suggest that you can not have multiple endpoints in a process, but this is an older post.  I have built a small sample against NServiceBus **6--beta4** that does work.

There is a similar question [NServiceBus Single Process, but Multiple Input queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694714/nservicebus-single-process-but-multiple-input-queues) that concluded, based on the OP's context using [Satellite Features](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/satellites) was the recommended approach.  **However,** in my case, I have 100 (functionally different) sagas (1 per queue), where each saga could need to receive similar messages, but I need to make sure that only the correct saga receives the message.  Therefor, I don't think implementing a custom feature will meet my requirements.  **Or will Satellite Features support Sagas?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the options is to use [self multi hosting](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/#self-hosting-multi-hosting). Using this approach, you self the endpoints yourself in the same process. There are a few things to take into consideration, such as:

- [Assembly scanning](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning) (might require custom scanning logic per endpoint).
- Throughput (for heavy throughput endpoints I'd recommend a separate hosting process).
- To update/redeploy a single endpoint, you'll be taking all of the other 99 endpoints down as well.

While there's no hard limit on how many endpoints can be co-hosted, 100 sounds a bit a lot. Saying that, it also depends how heavy the load on those endpoints is. If you process 1 msg/sec or 1K msg/sec determine a lot if this is a viable option or not.

Have a look at the [sample](http://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/multi-hosting/) that does exactly that.

Comment: Re: assembly scanning, was planning on using the `config.excludetypes` method to make sure each saga was the only one handler per endpoint was picked up.  Or is there a more efficient way to optimize nsb assembly scanning (still need to look at your links)